# CMAKE suppress error output for custom command?

Tags: bash, cmake

I have a cmake command that looks like the following:

```
add_custom_command(
        TARGET "uninstall"
        POST_BUILD
        COMMENT "Uninstall files within install_manifest.txt"
        COMMAND sudo xargs rm -vf < install_manifest.txt || echo Nothing in install_manifest.txt to be uninstalled!
        COMMAND cat install_manifest.txt | xargs -L1 dirname | sudo xargs rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -p
        COMMAND echo 
)
```

which has the goal of uninstalling files that were installed as part of the package.

The line

`COMMAND sudo xargs rm -vf < install_manifest.txt || echo Nothing in install_manifest.txt to be uninstalled!` is to remove the individual files that were installed, and `COMMAND cat install_manifest.txt | xargs -L1 dirname | sudo xargs rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -p` was to clear up the empty directories left behind.

Unfortunately, when I run the `make uninstall` I see the following near the end:

```
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/include/palisade/pke': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/include/palisade/binfhe': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/include/palisade/binfhe': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/include/palisade/binfhe': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/include/palisade/binfhe': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/include/palisade/binfhe': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/include/palisade/binfhe': No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/uninstall.dir/build.make:72: uninstall] Error 123
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:334: CMakeFiles/uninstall.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:341: CMakeFiles/uninstall.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:183: uninstall] Error 2
```

which I want to avoid. If I had to guess, the issue comes about because as `rmdir` is deleting folders, it is deleting their parents which means that for some other files which are along the same branch, it cannot access the empty folders there which is causing the errors. Does anyone know how I might address this? I don't want to propagate those errors to the user because for all intents and purposes it shouldn't matter to them

Comment: One solution would be to write a **shell script** and run that script via `add_custom_command`. Inside that script you could have a better control for exit code (no needs to make every script line to success), and inside `add_custom_command` you could redirect the whole script's output into `/dev/null` (redirecting piped commands, as in your current code, would be much more difficult).

Answer (score 0):

It will happen because the CMake command "add_custom_command" will halt execution if any of its COMMAND gives error (non-zero error code).

One workaround is to make sure that the command always succeeds by using "echo"

```
(some_shell_command || echo "")
```

For your example code :

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET "uninstall"
    POST_BUILD
    COMMENT "Uninstall files within install_manifest.txt"
    COMMAND sudo xargs rm -vf < install_manifest.txt || echo Nothing in install_manifest.txt to be uninstalled!
    COMMAND cat install_manifest.txt | xargs -L1 dirname | sudo xargs rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -p || echo ""
    COMMAND echo 
)
```

might work